# remove duplicate images from wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress

I want to know about that how to remove duplicate images from wordpress media library  and i also want to ask that how media uploader checks duplication of file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get all posts. See get_posts( array ( 'numberposts' => -1 ) )
For each post get all attachments. See get_children( array ( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1 ) )
For each attachment get the attachment URL. See wp_get_attachment_url()
If you find the attachment URL in the parent post's content ($post->post_content):
    If there is another attachment URL with the same file name plus the 1 and
    both are part of the post content then
    remove the second image first then
    use wp_delete_attachment() to delete the physical file. This will remove all meta data and all associations in other posts too. It is the best way to remove attached files (imho).
```

Comment: Thanks. when upload image from upload new media(media-new.php) than upper code works or not?

Comment: how can i check when upload new image in new media?

Answer (score 0):

> Clean up unused images and other files from your uploads folder.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-janitor/

> Delete not used image

http://wordpress.org/plugins/dnui-delete-not-used-image-wordpress/screenshots/

> when not use plugin:

```
go media:   Sort files by Unattached.

delete which is not used.
```

Comment: how can i check when upload new image that image already exists in media?